# How can I replace a value in a List using an iterator ( Java )

Tags: java, list, arraylist, iterator

So basically I'm writing a simple program where the user inputs a string and then that string is turned into a List where every occurrence of the second to last element is replaced with the last one.

So if the program inputs
a b c a b c
the program outputs
a c c a c

This is what I got so far but I can't run the program for some reason I was wondering what I'm doing wrong.

```
public static void  main(String args[])
{
    
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Enter in list");
String s = input.nextLine();

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")));


String replacewith;
String replace;

replacewith = list.get(list.size()-1);
replace = list.get(list.size()-2);

Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
int i = 0;

while(iterator.hasNext()) {
   String value = iterator.next();
   
   if(value.equals(replace))
   {  
       iterator.remove();
       list.add(i,replacewith);
       
   }
   i++;
}

System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: Iterator is expecting that only modifications to list will be done via that iterator (until it will finish iterating). So you can't use `list.add(i,replacewith);` while iteration is not finished.

Comment: @Pshemo ah I see, do you know another way for me to add the intended value to that index then?

Comment: Honestly I am not sure I understand your task correctly. Since task is "every occurrence of the second to last element is *replaced* with the last one" how `a b c a b c` (6 characters, second is `b`) became `a c c a c` (why 5 characters? why `a` was not replaced?)

Comment: Anyway if you want to replace some elements while iterating you can use `ListIterator` instead of `Iterator` and call its `set(newValue)` method.

Comment: @Pshemo Thank you! I completely forgot about List Iterator, and yes you misunderstood what I was trying to do but no worries since you gave the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java8 streams to solve your problem.

```
    String replaceWith = "c";
    String replace = "b";
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c").stream()
            .map(c -> c.equals(replace) ? replaceWith : c)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Thank you for this, never tried using java8 since I'm fairly new to java, but this worked!